# buscar dados do omdbapi

Tags: php, html, json

Tenho este codigo (meusite.com/imdb.php)

```
<?php
$movie_id = 'tt0387564';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' . $movie_id . '&plot=short&apikey=') , true);
$data2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' . $movie_id . '?language=pt-PT&api_key=') , true);
if (empty($movie_id))
{
    echo '';
    die();
}

echo '
<div class="container">
<div class="poster"><img src="' . $data['Poster'] . '"/></div>
<div class="Title">' . $data['Title'] . '</div>
<div class="Year">' . $data['Year'] . '</div>
<div class="Genre">' . $data['Genre'] . '</div>
<div class="imdbRating">' . $data['imdbRating'] . '</div>
<div class="Director">' . $data['Director'] . '</div>
<div class="Actors">' . $data['Actors'] . '</div>
<div class="overview">' . $data2['overview'] . '</div>
</div>
';
?>
```

Como faço para buscar o `&movie_id` sem ter que alterar sempre o ficheiro .php?
Exemplo: `meusite.com/imdb.php?movie_id=tt0387564`

Comment: Como assim alterar o ficheiro?

Comment: os meus conhecimentos de php são muito poucos, o que eu queria era ir buscar as informações dos filmes pelo movie_id sem ter de alterar o ficheiro php, por exemplo assim: meusite.com/imdb.php?movieid=tt*****

Comment: Ah, ok, entendo. Qual retorno está obtendo?

Comment: já consegui, era só adicionar estas linhas
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['movieid'])) {
    die('require param movieid');
}
$movie_id = $_GET['movieid'];

// debug
// var_dump($movie_id); die;